# Background-attachment is fixed everywhere

Tags: css, sass

I have a problem with background-attachment property. Namely I used it on desktop, but it also appears on mobile. Why is that? Here is my code:

```
main {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: inherit;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url("./images/main.jpg");
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    background-attachment: initial;
    height: 800px;
  }
}
```

EDIT: Updated code

Comment: because it's defined as fixed in your code and everywhere. what's the issue then ?

Comment: Sorry, pasted wrong code. I meant that when I'm trying to change this to initial it is still fixed.

Comment: not sure if this is a valid sass syntax ... but can you try the media query outside

Comment: it didn't change anything

Comment: Does this work? main {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: inherit;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: initial;
  background-image: url("./images/main.jpg");
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    background-attachment: initial;
    height: 800px;
  }
} try plz

Answer (score 0):

```
main { height: 800px; background-color: inherit; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: cover; background-attachment: initial; background-image: url("./images/main.jpg"); @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { background-attachment: initial; height: 800px; } }
```